# problems with bootstrap navbar toggle

Tags: html

i switched from msn bootstrap to bootstrap which i uploaded manually.
 i am doing this project on cloud 9. 
when the screen is small enouth the nav bar has a button on the right,
which drops the navbar down and displays my other links
 which now does not work. 
it might be the jquery but i have no idea if i put it in here or if i did so correctly
any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> inclass-project </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>


        <!--start of nav-->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Adrw4's Site</a>
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navbar-collapse">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
         </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="Index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="About.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="Contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="Test.html" class="nav-link">Test</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>


      <!--end of nav section-->


    <section class="hero-section">
      <div class="container">
        <form action="/action_page.php">

         <label for="fname">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">

         <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..">

         <label for="country">Country</label>
         <select id="country" name="country">
          <option value="usa">Usa</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="england">England</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
         </select>

         <label for="subject">Subject</label>
         <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write something.." style="height:200px"></textarea>

         <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
      </div>
    </section>



      <!-- start of footer-->

      <footer class="footer-container">
        <div class="social-media-container left">
         <a href="Https://Www.Facebook.com" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
         <a href="https://www.instagram.com/" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-container left">
          <span>dsafdsf</span>
          <span class="address">fgfggf</span>
           <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Adrw4 All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="social-media-container right">
      <a href="https://github.com/" class="fa fa-github"></a>
      <a href="https://www.snapchat.com/" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a>
        </div>
      </footer>

      <!--end of footer-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
data-target="navbar-collapse"
```

to

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse"
```

I used your navigation in here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: THANK YOU! SO MUCH!!!!! I apologize for the poor grammar i've been doing this all day today.